# Regedit, Always start an specific exe file with parameter

Tags: windows, regedit

I need to know is there any way to start specific exe file like 1231413.exe with --testmode 1 parameter.

Comment: Try adding e.g. `1231413.exe --testmode 1` to a batch file and start that instead?

Comment: I know that way but, I need to do this in Regedit

Comment: Is this for a file-extension and which?

Comment: Why are you constrained to only accomplish this via the registry?